# Electric on bath cabinet side

Tags: electrical, bathroom, code-compliance

Is it allowed by NEC to install an outlet into the side of a bath cabinet like in the picture.  I want to cut a section of the cabinet side for a box and then punch a hole in the back wall and run the line down.

In my specific situation I can not install it on the front wall.  this is just an example picture not the actual.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a code expert, but the only concern I see is that the cable is protected inside the cabinet. You might run flexible conduit form a suitable box to the wall opening. Of course, you'll need to have the outlet protected by a GFCI, either itself or slaved to another nearby one.

Comment: Yes, isherwood is right, you might want BX (or MC) cable... I've seen this done in kitchen cabinets.

Comment: if that cabinet is movable, the NEC would not permit a Permanent wired outlet into a cabinet that might get moved. if it is fixed into position, it may be permissible. alternatively, it could have an outlet put into it, and have a cord run to an outlet in a fixed position some other place.

Comment: Cords to an outlet are not legal. A flexible metal conduit or armor clad where exposed inside the cabinet would be. A GFCI would be required as Isherwood said. Gave a + when I read this the first time.